# Getting a custom JPanel to show custom JComponents (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I am seriously at a loss with this one guys. I am trying to create a custom LED display to show 7 bars arranged as an 8. I got a single custom JComponent (bar) to show inside of a JFrame, but I cannot get the bars to show inside of the custom panel that I am creating. Here is the code for the constructor methods and the paint methods in my classes as well as the main method that I am using to test these classes.

The custom JComponent:

```
public class Bar extends JComponent
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private static boolean litUp = false;
    private static boolean vertical = false;
    private static boolean rotated = false;
    private static boolean rotClockwise = false;
    private static int positionX;
    private static int positionY;



    public Bar(boolean lit, boolean vert, int posX, int posY)
    {
        litUp = lit;
        vertical = vert;
        positionX = posX;
        positionY = posY;
        repaint();
        System.out.println("The bar is being initialized");
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("BAR: Paint Component being called");

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;

        if(vertical == true)
        {
            if(litUp == true)
            {
                g2D.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            else
            {
                g2D.setColor(Color.black);
            }

            g2D.drawRect(positionX , positionY, 10, 30);
            g2D.fillRect(positionX , positionY, 10, 30);
            System.out.println("BAR: fillRect is being called for a vertical bar");
            if(rotated == true)
            {
                if(rotClockwise == true)
                {
                    g2D.rotate(0.3398);
                }
                else
                {
                    g2D.rotate(-0.3398);
                }
            }

        }

        else{

            System.out.println("BAR: fillRect is being called for a horizontal bar");
            if(litUp == true)
            {
                g2D.setColor(Color.red);
            }
            else
            {
                g2D.setColor(Color.black);
            }
            g2D.drawRect(positionX,positionY, 30, 10);
            g2D.fillRect(positionX,positionY, 30, 10);
        }


    }
}
```

The Custom JPanel:

```
public class LED extends JPanel
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    //private static Bar[] bars = new Bar[7];
    //private static int xPos;
    //private static int yPos;

    private  Bar barZero;
    private  Bar barOne;
    private  Bar barTwo;
    private  Bar barThree;
    private  Bar barFour;
    private  Bar barFive;
    private  Bar barSix;




    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class LED
     */
    public LED()
    {
        barZero = new Bar(false, false,  0, 0);
        this.add(barZero);
       // barZero.setDirection(false);
        barOne = new Bar(false, true, 0, 11);
        this.add(barOne);
        //barOne.setDirection(true);
        barTwo = new Bar(false, true, 20, 11);
        this.add(barTwo);
        //barTwo.setDirection(true);
        barThree = new Bar(false, false, 0, 42);
        this.add(barThree);
        //barThree.setDirection(false);
        barFour = new Bar(false, true, 0, 53);
        this.add(barFour);
        //barFour.setDirection(true);
        barFive = new Bar(false, true, 20, 53);
        this.add(barFive);
        //barFive.setDirection(true);
        barSix = new Bar(false, false, 0, 64);
        this.add(barSix);
        //barSix.setDirection(false);



        System.out.println("The LED class is being accessed");

        repaint();
    }

@ Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("LED: PaintComponent being called");
        //barOne.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("LED: barZero being painted| " + barZero.orientation() + "|  " + barZero.coordX());

        System.out.println("LED: barOne being painted| " + barOne.orientation() + "|  " + barOne.coordX());
        //barTwo.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("LED: barTwo being painted| " + barTwo.orientation() + "|  " + barTwo.coordX());

        //barThree.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("LED: barThree being painted| " + barThree.orientation() + "|  " + barThree.coordX());
        //barFour.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("LED: barFour being painted| " + barFour.orientation() + "|  " + barFour.coordX());
        //barFive.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("LED: barFive being painted| " + barFive.orientation() + "|  " + barFive.coordX());
        //barSix.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("LED: barSix being painted| " + barSix.orientation() + "|  " + barSix.coordX());


        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

And the Tester Method:

```
public class DrawRect {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    LED led = new LED()
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    window.getContentPane().add(led);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

I can get initialize a Bar and have it display in the Frame, but I cannot get the LED (Panel) to show bars in it. Also, here is the strings that are printed out from testing the component. None of the bars that I am adding have their values set: they are all horizontal and they all have their x positions set to 0. I am not one to give up, but this program is making me want to change my major.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).  That means one source file (possibly with more than one class file inside) with imports, as opposed to three.

Comment: A custom component should override `getPreferredSize()` to provide the layout manager with hints as to size.

Comment: An unrelated issue but your Bar class has multiple inappropriate uses of the static modifier. Most of those fields should be instance fields, not static fields.

Comment: Another suggestion: use an array or List to store the `Bar`s in your custom panel. This will make it really easy to paint them all with a for loop.

Comment: took out the static modifier and added the Bars to an array. A little fuzzy on the getPreferredSize() method for the Bar class. There will be two sizes for the component. Do you still suggest to have it overridden?

Comment: What everyone else said, plus Swing is not thread safe.  Tester method or not, please do all Swing code on the [Event Dispatch Thread.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: Oh one other thing, when you call g2d.rotate() in the Bar class paintComponent() method, you normally need to call that first to set the rotation, then call the drawing method (like a drawRectangle).

Answer (score 4):

So you're pretty close.  I think the best thing you can do is reduce complexity even more than using an ArrayList, and just use a component that already exists.  Here's a simpler example using a HorizontalBox.

I only show one orientation and one size, but I think you can work the rest out by yourself.  There may be an error in the paintComponent() routine that's off by one pixel.  I can't squint hard enough at the screen to be sure.

Also don't forget about the whole multi-threading thing.  On the Event Dispatch Thread, please.  I have a couple of macros in my IDE that basically builds the code for the EDT in about two seconds.  No excuses.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class LedBar extends JComponent
{
   private final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension( 20, 50 );
   private float value = 50f; // range 0-100

   public void setValue( float value )
   {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public float getValue()
   {
      return value;
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      g.setColor( Color.RED );
      g.drawRect( 0, 0, SIZE.width, SIZE.height );
      g.setColor( Color.RED.darker() );
      final int top = (int)(SIZE.height*(100f-value)/100f+1);
      final int bottom = (int)(SIZE.height*(value)/100f-1);
      g.fillRect( 1, top, SIZE.width-1, bottom);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return SIZE;
   }
}

class Test
{
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            Box hbox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               LedBar led = new LedBar();
               led.setValue( i * 20f );
               hbox.add( led );
            }
            frame.add( hbox );

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
            frame.setVisible( true );
         }
      } );
   }
}
```

Comment: `class Test { public static void main( String[] args ) {..` Huh.  That's the first time I recall seeing a non `public` class with a `main(String[])` pasted in at the end of the source of a different `public` class.  Why not copy/paste the main into the public class and discard the `test` class altogether?

Comment: Well, because then the main method would be part of the LedBar class.  As is, the Test class is separate and never adds bytes to the LedBar class file.  (My IDE will find any class with a main method in a source file and run it, so this is just a convenient way of making two classes -- one class and one test class -- in a single source file.)

Comment: @markspace I am definitely still hitting some multi-threading problems. I have a print statement in the paintComponent method of the Bar class. The tester class is written with invoke later, and I am making one bar and adding it to the frame, but I am still getting multiple print statements for the one bar. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues you need to consider here:

1. Each `Bar` object needs its own variables to keep track of its state. This means that the member variables in `Bar` should **not** be static.
2. A custom component needs to override `getPreferredSize()` in order to tell its parent container how much space the custom component wants to take.
3. The **parent container** is responsible for determining the position of the components it contains. (More appropriately, this is the responsibility of the LayoutManager.) This means it is inappropriate to have the x and y positions in the custom component.
4. In `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, you are only allowed to draw within the area that is owned by the component. The coordinates are relative to the top left corner of the component, **not** relative to the top left of the container which holds it. This means that you need to draw a rectangle covering the full component:

   ```
   g.drawRectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
   ```
5. You can reduce some of the complexity of your code by using an array or `List` to store the `Bar` objects inside your custom panel. For example, you will then be able to paint each `Bar` in a simple for loop.